# Fast way to enlarge a triangle

Tags: math, geometry, transform, computational-geometry

I have a triangle, defined by its 3 (suppose integer) coordinates, say:

```
A(ax, ay) B(bx, by) C(cx, cy)
```

how can I "enlarge" the `ABC` triangle to obtain a new one (`DEF`) that is the **minimum** (smallest area) triangle with integer coordinates which contains all the vertices of the previous?

For example, if I have the triangle ABC how can I obtain the triangle DEF?

[image: example]

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Have you made any attempts on this problem, and do you have any code to show? Have you tried moving each vertex one step in each of the 8 main directions (up, up-right, right, etc.) and checking each of those resulting triangles?

Comment: Maybe checking on how to [find the area of overlap of two triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154628/find-the-area-of-overlap-of-two-triangles) is a good start.

Comment: May any of the coordinates remain the same?  In your example, if `D` moved to  (-3, 0), F=B, and E=C, is that a solution?

Comment: I think you may be better of asking this question at [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Following approach in `python 2.7` may be a fair solution to your problem.

```
from itertools import combinations, product
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Triangle(object):

    def __str__(self):
        return "Triangle: " + str(self.vertices)

    def __init__(self,A,B,C):
        """ Creates a Triangle of vertices A,B,C """
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.C = C
        self.vertices = [A,B,C]

    def area(self):
        """ Area of the triangle """
        x1 = self.A[0]
        y1 = self.A[1]
        x2 = self.B[0]
        y2 = self.B[1]
        x3 = self.C[0]
        y3 = self.C[1]
        return abs((x1 * (y2 - y3) + x2 * (y3 - y1)
                + x3 * (y1 - y2)) / 2.0)

    def isInside(self,X):
        """ Function to check whether X lies inside the triangle """
        area = self.area()
        area1 = Triangle(X,self.B,self.C).area()
        area2 = Triangle(self.A,X,self.C).area()
        area3 = Triangle(self.A,self.B,X).area()
        # Check if sum of area1, area2 and area3 is same as area
        if(area == area1 + area2 + area3):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def findPosibleIntegerTriangles(self):
        """ Find posible triangles moving vertices to next integer values (512 posible triangles) """
        posibleA = posiblePoints(self.A)
        posibleB = posiblePoints(self.B)
        posibleC = posiblePoints(self.C)
        listPosibleVertices =  list(product(*[posibleA, posibleB, posibleC]))
        posibleTriangles = [Triangle(A,B,C) for A,B,C in listPosibleVertices ]
        return posibleTriangles

    def findPosibleIncludingIntegerTriangles(self):
        """ Find those posible triangles that include the original triangle """
        posibleIncludingTriangles = list()
        posibleTriangles = self.findPosibleIntegerTriangles()
        for triangle in posibleTriangles:
            if self.isTriangleIncluded(triangle):
                posibleIncludingTriangles.append(triangle)
        return posibleIncludingTriangles

    def isTriangleIncluded(self,triangle):
        """ Checks if it's included in the triangle selected (DEF) """
        DNotInside = not self.isInside(triangle.A)
        ENotInside = not self.isInside(triangle.B)
        FNotInside = not self.isInside(triangle.C)
        D = triangle.A
        E = triangle.B
        F = triangle.C
        ABdoNotIntersectDE = not segmentsIntersect(self.A,self.B,D,E)
        ABdoNotIntersectEF = not segmentsIntersect(self.A,self.B,E,F)
        ABdoNotIntersectFD = not segmentsIntersect(self.A,self.B,F,D)
        BCdoNotIntersectDE = not segmentsIntersect(self.B,self.C,D,E)
        BCdoNotIntersectEF = not segmentsIntersect(self.B,self.C,E,F)
        BCdoNotIntersectFD = not segmentsIntersect(self.B,self.C,F,D)
        CAdoNotIntersectDE = not segmentsIntersect(self.C,self.A,D,E)
        CAdoNotIntersectEF = not segmentsIntersect(self.C,self.A,E,F)
        CAdoNotIntersectFD = not segmentsIntersect(self.C,self.A,F,D)
        return DNotInside and ENotInside and FNotInside and \
                ABdoNotIntersectDE and ABdoNotIntersectEF and ABdoNotIntersectFD and \
                BCdoNotIntersectDE and BCdoNotIntersectEF and BCdoNotIntersectFD and \
                CAdoNotIntersectDE and CAdoNotIntersectEF and CAdoNotIntersectFD

    def findMinimumIntegerTriangle(self):
        """ Find the minimum triangle enlarged by integer values that includes the original triangle """
        minimumIntegerTriangle = None
        area = None
        for triangle in self.findPosibleIncludingIntegerTriangles():
            if area == None:
                area = triangle.area()
                minimumIntegerTriangle = triangle
            else:
                if triangle.area() < area:
                    area = triangle.area
                    minimumIntegerTriangle = triangle

        return minimumIntegerTriangle

    def plot(self, color = "blue"):
        pol = plt.Polygon(np.array(self.vertices),color = color)
        plt.gca().add_patch(pol)
        plt.autoscale()

def posiblePoints(P):
    """ Determine posible points to move to """
    posibleX = range(P[0]-1,P[0]+2)
    posibleY = range(P[1]-1,P[1]+2)
    posibleP = []
    for x in posibleX:
        for y in posibleY:
            if x!=P[0] or y!=P[1]:
                posibleP.append((x,y))
    return posibleP

def segmentsIntersect(A,B,C,D):
    """ Check if segment AB instersects with CD """
    def ccw(A,B,C):
        return (C[1]-A[1]) * (B[0]-A[0]) > (B[1]-A[1]) * (C[0]-A[0])
    return ccw(A,C,D) != ccw(B,C,D) and ccw(A,B,C) != ccw(A,B,D)

# Select the vertices of original triangle
A = (-2,0)
B = (4,0)
C = (-1,3)

# Define the triangle
T = Triangle(A,B,C)

# Find the minimum triangle enlarged by integer values that includes the original triangle and print it
Tmin = T.findMinimumIntegerTriangle()
print Tmin

# Plot the found minimum triangle and the original one
Tmin.plot("red")
T.plot("blue")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The code has a `Triangle` class. The Triangle object is defined by three vertices, which are tuples, and has defined functions `area` to calculate the triangles area, `isInside` to check whether a point lies inside the triangle, `findPosibleIntegerTriangles` to find possible triangles, `isTriangleIncluded` to checks if it's included in a certain triangle, and `findMinimumIntegerTriangle` which finds its "minimum triangle" (if any).

To find the "minimum triangle" it looks for all the possible "integer triangles" which result by moving the three vertices in each direction by one unit (512 possibilities in total). Then from those possible triangles check whether the vertices are outside the original triangle and ensure as well that none of its sides intersect any of the original triangle's segments (if both conditions are True then the triangle would include the original triangle). Finally from those possible "integer triangles" find which has the minimum area.

The program outputs the coordinates of vertices for the "minimum triangle" (by printing the `Triangle` object `Tmin` found as solution) and plots the "minimum triangle" and the original triangle.

The outputs are:

```
>>> 
Triangle: [(-3, -1), (5, 0), (-1, 4)]
```

[image: Original triangle and "minimum triangle]

Comment: Beware that there are some triangles that don't have a corresponding "minimum triangle". e.g. triangle `[(-2, 2), (4, 0), (-1, 3)]`. Not sure though which condition they should have to ensure there is a solution.

Comment: I also suspect that as the triange gets a more severe "aspect ratio", that you might have to look at more than just the nearest integer points.  For example, consider [(0,0), (999999999999999,2), (999999999999999,1)]...it's not immediately obvious the tiny extension in length to look 2 integer steps away near the long axis has a significant impact on total area.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b, Just for the note, for the triangle you mention the "minimum triangle" I get from the program I posted is: `Triangle: [(1, 1), (1000000000000000L, 3), (999999999999998L, 2)]`

Comment: @CedricCoppolo Heh. I didn't actually work out a counterexample, I was just trying to illustrate the general idea.  For a sufficiently ill-aspected triangle, "nearest integer" may not be as important as "exact alignment with the longest axis"

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer:**

The vertices of the new triangle must belong to the outer angles of the original triangle (obtained by lengthening the sides).

Then new candidate vertices are found as the first grid point met when moving a line parallel to a side away from the opposite corner.

[image]

I am unsure if this necessarily gives the optimal solution. For safety, you can try the immediate neighbors of the candidates and check if any combination yields a smaller area.

Comment: I think the correct solution lies in this direction; It is consistent with the algorithm for finding a minimum convex hull containing a set of points.  To be optimal, it probably needs a way to weight the search of the corner regions in some way by the length of the triangle sides.

Answer (score 0):

### This answer applies **only** if you want to scale homogeneously the triangle.

---

Let's translate the triangle so vertex `A(ax,ay)` becomes origin `(0,0)`.

The traslated vertices now are `B'(bx-ax,by-ay)=(ux,uy)` and `C'=(cx-ax,cy-ay)=(vx,vy)`.

When a scale factor `F` is applied to a coordinate `x'= x·F` we have an increment `d= x'-x`. So we can also say `x'= x+d` and thus `F= x'/x = (x+d)/x = 1 + d/x`.

Let's apply the same scale to translated `B'` and `C'`:

```
F= 1 + d1/ux
F= 1 + d2/uy
F= 1 + d3/vx
F= 1 + d4/vy
```

Because `F` is the same for the four equalities we have:

```
d2/uy = d1/ux   ==>>   d2·ux = d1·uy  ==>> d2·ux - d1·uy = 0
d3/vx = d1/ux   ==>>   d3·ux = d1·vx  ==>> d3·ux - d1·vx = 0
d4/vy = d1/ux   ==>>   d4·ux = d1·vy  ==>> d4·ux - d1·vy = 0
```

Any equation in the form `ax+by=0` has the `(-b,a)` solution. So:

```
d1 = ux
d2 = uy
d3 = vx
d4 = vy
```

If `ux,uy,vx,vy` have a maximum common divisor `g` then we find the lowest scale factor:

From the first equality:

```
ux = ux'·g   ==>> g= ux/ux'
uy = uy'·g
d2·ux'·g - d1·uy'·g = 0   ==>>   d2·ux' - d1·uy' = 0
```

which means that `d1 = ux'` is also a solution.

The scale factor is:

```
F= (ux + d1)/ux = 1 + ux'/ux  =  1 + 1/g
```

Translating back the coordinates we have for example vertex `B`:

```
b_scaled_x = (bx-ax) · F + ax
b_scaled_y = (by-ay) · F + ay
```

Notice that all coordinates and increments `di` and maximum common divisior `g`are integer values. The scale factor `F` is a rational number. So the calculus must be done on 'floats' instead of 'integers'.